# Smarter include guard in C++ to include headers several times inside different namespaces

Tags: c++, macros, namespaces, include, preprocessor

I need a way to do better `#include` guarding in C++.

When the same header is included twice, the second `#include` should be ignored (which is simple thing to do):

```
#include "header1.hpp"
#include "header2.hpp"
#include "header1.hpp" //Should be ignored
```

But when the same header is included inside nested namespace, then it should be included again (but not more than once per namespace):

```
#include "header1.hpp"
#include "header2.hpp"

namespace foo_namespace {
    //May be this one is needed?
    #define NAMESPACE_ID foo_namespace

    #include "header1.hpp" //Should be included again
    #include "header1.hpp" //Should be ignored

    #undef NAMESPACE_ID
};
```

The question is: how should I guard the code inside `header1.hpp`?
Additional requirement is that guard itself should be reusable (defined as a macro), since I have lots of headers that should be guarded this way.

Comment: I wonder why you need a file to be included twice?

Comment: I need two versions of all structures and functions. First version with `double` floating-point datatype, second version with `float` floating-point datatype.

Comment: Have you thought about using a template to determine the datatype? Then you do not have to have the code twice.

Comment: Then I need to make templates for everything. And, besides datatype, these header inclusions may have other minor differences, such as deleted constructors in one version, some missing functions in other version etc.

Comment: I understand that I can make each class and each function and each typedef inside the header as a template which depends on `<bool VERSION>`, then add SFINAE and other template magic to disable or modify datatypes and functions depending on `VERSION`. But I decided instead to have nested namespace, and include header second time with some additional `typedef`s and `#define`s before `#include`.

Answer (score 2):

A decent solution would be to have a version of the header without guards:

```
// header_noguard.hpp
// the declarations ...


// header.hpp
#pragma once // or a macro of your choice
#include "header_noguard.hpp"

// header_namespace.hpp
#pragma once // or a macro of your choice
namespace foo_namespace {
    #include "header_noguard.hpp"
};
```

Now, you can include `header.hpp` and `header_namespace.hpp` multiple times. Each is guarded against multiple inclusion, but both contain the declarations in their respective namespaces.